# Boundary $\partial F_n$ of a free group $F_n$

Tags: geometric-group-theory, automorphism-group

I am reading "The Tits alternative for $\operatorname{Out}(F_n)$ I: Dynamics of exponentially-growing automorphisms" by Mladen Bestvina et al. for my Master's thesis. On page 526, the following part can be found: [image]

I have some questions concerning this part of the text:

1. "The circle at infinity is replaced by the Cantor set $\partial F_n$ of ends of $F_n$. I looked up what the "end" of a group is and got redirected to the wikipedia page about the "end of a graph". What I understood from this is that an end of a graph is an equivalence class of lines and that the ends of a group are the ends of the associated Cayley graphs. However, I do not understand **there is a unique line $\tilde{\sigma} \subset \Gamma$ connecting the ends $c_1$ and $c_2$**
2. What is the **the diagonal action of $F_n$ on $\partial F_n \times \partial F_n$?** I know what a diagonal action of a group on a set is, but what is the action of $F_n$ on its boundary?
3. What are **covering translations**? I know what covering transformations are, so is this just the same thing denoted by a different name?

Comment: If $G$ acts on a set $X$ the diagonal action of $G$ on $X^n$ is just the action $g\cdot (x_1,\dots,x_n)=(gx_1,\dots,gx_n)$. For instance when $n=2$ there are other ways to product an action, sometimes naturally occurring, such as $g\cdot (x,y)=(gx,y)$ (product of the given action and of the trivial action).

Comment: @YCor thank you, but I knew what a diagonal action is. However, in this case they talked about **THE** action of $F_n$ on the boundary, so I wondered what action this specifically is. I think this is the general action of a group on its Cayleygraph, but was not really sure.

Comment: Oops, I was confused about the wording. The isometry group of any hyperbolic space acts on the boundary. This applies in particular for the group of left translations on the right Cayley graph, for a hyperbolic group.

Comment: @YCor so meaning that if there is an edge between $g_1$ and $g_2$ than the action maps the edge to the one between $gg_1$ and $gg_2$? (So by left multiplication?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean: by right Cayley graph, I meant that $G$ has a finite generating subset $S$, and there's an edge between $g$ and $gs$ for all $g\in G$ and $s\in S$. This graph structure being left-invariant, the left action is an isometric action.

Comment: @YCor I am just trying to verify what 'the left action' in this case is; Is it the usual action of a group on its right Cayley graph (left multiplication)?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @YCor Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is a (locally path connected) topological space that has an exhaustion $K_1\subset K_2\subset\dots \subset X$ by compact sets.  Each complement $X-K_i$ has some number of connected components, written $\pi_0(X-K_i)$.  When $i\geq j$, there is an induced map $f_{ij}:\pi_0(X-K_i)\to \pi_0(X-K_j)$ that "fuses" connected components.  An *end* of $X$ is an element of the inverse limit of this system.  More concretely, an end is a sequence $\{U_i\}_i$ with $U_i\in\pi_0(X-K_i)$ and $f_{ij}(U_i)=U_j$.  More intuitively, an end is a sequence of more-and-more-refined connected components in the complement of a closed ball of ever-increasing radius.  We topologize the space of ends by declaring, for each open $V\subset X$, that the set of all ends that eventually lie in $V$ is open

For a finitely generated group $G$, we define the ends of $G$ to be the ends of its Cayley graph (or more generally the ends of a topological space that $G$ acts "geometrically" on, if I recall correctly what I've heard at various geometric group theory talks I've attended; this means "properly" and "cocompactly").  It turns out it doesn't matter which generating set you choose: there will be a homeomorphism between the ends of the first Cayley graph to the ends of the second Cayley graph.

The ends of $F_n$ are straightforward to describe.  If we choose the natural generating set of $F_n$, the Cayley graph $\Gamma$ is a tree where every vertex is degree $2n$.  Let $K_i$ be the set of all points that are within distance $i$ of the identity's vertex, where the distance is given by saying each edge has unit length.  Connected components of $\Gamma-K_i$ can be described as paths from the identity's vertex, and in particular there is a unique reduced word in $F_n$ of minimal length that corresponds to such a path.  The ends, then, are described by "infinitely long reduced words" in $F_n$, for instance $abababa\dotsc,$ which should be thought of as a limit of finite reduced words.  The topology on the ends is the same as having a basis indexed by reduced words $w$ in $F_n$ of all infinite reduced words that have $w$ as a prefix.  This is like the product topology on $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, and in both cases they are homeomorphic to the Cantor set.

These infinite reduced words are the "lines" or "geodesics" in the Cayley graph of $F_n$.  Because the Cayley graph is a connected tree, there is a unique non-backtracking line between any two points.  A line between ends can be described entirely by the two end-points.  This is $\partial F_n\times \partial F_n$.  But the end-points must be distinct, hence we subtract the diagonal.  But also we don't care about the direction of the line, so we mod by the $Z_2$ action.

*Covering translations* are the same as *covering transformations*.  I think the point is that every line between ends can be translated by covering transformations, but what happens to the end-points is described by the $F_n$ action on $\partial F_n$.  Furthermore, every line can be described by a pair of reduced infinite words that each start from the identity's vertex, with the understanding that they might have a common prefix, representing the exact covering transformation whose inverse would bring that line to the identity's vertex.

Comment: I quickly read your answer (on mobile) and will reread later this afternoon, but I had one more question: how does $F_n$ act on $\partial F_n$? Thanks a lot for your answer, this will definitely help me!

Comment: Or is this just by left multiplication (if this makes any sense)?

Comment: I thought I remembered to mention it, but it seems like I didn't.  The group acts on the ends by covering translations, and concretely this is left multiplication by the group (and I guess you need to simplify the resulting infinite word).

Comment: one more question: would you happen to have some references concerning ends of groups? I have to understand them very well for my master's thesis, but I only find articles assuming I already know about this...

Comment: Sorry, my only sources have been colleagues and talks.  Suggestion 1: trace through the references in those articles, because eventually someone might give basic theory. Suggestion 2: look for an introduction to geometric group theory.  One such book I randomly pulled up suggests "M. Bridson and A. Haefliger, Metric spaces of non-positive curvature, SpringerVerlag, Berlin, 1999." and "R. Geoghegan, Topological methods in group theory, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, vol. 243, Springer, New York, 2008."

Comment: I also just found The Theory of Ends by Georg Peschke, which seems to be a rather nice survey article. https://sites.ualberta.ca/~gepe/pdf/Peschke_TheoryOfEnds.pdf